# break axis labels in R (Using sjp.frq function)

Tags: r, graph, axis-labels, frequency-analysis

I'm making some frequency graphs using the `sjp.frq` function, but the axis labels are to big and I would like to break those in two lines. The [image: graph] shows that the axis labels are one on the top of the other. How do I change this?

Thanks for the help!

```
library(sjPlot)
library(sjmisc)

set_theme(base = theme_classic(),  axis.title.size = 0,  geom.label.size = 4.5, 
                  axis.textsize.x = 1.1, axis.textsize.y = 1.1 )

sjp.frq(base$x, type = c("bar"), sort.frq = c("desc"), geom.colors = "grey")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although no sample data is given, here's are two fixes that may work

```
library(sjPlot)
library(sjmisc)

set_theme(base = theme_classic(),  axis.title.size = 0,  geom.label.size = 4.5, 
                  axis.textsize.x = 1.1, axis.textsize.y = 1.1 )

sjp.frq(base$x, type = c("bar"), sort.frq = c("desc"), geom.colors = "grey",coord.flip =TRUE) #Flip the corrdinate and check if that avoids the overlap.
```

If the above does't work, try setting the axis.angle.x argument as follows

```
library(sjPlot)
library(sjmisc)

set_theme(base = theme_classic(),  axis.title.size = 0,  geom.label.size = 4.5, 
                  axis.textsize.x = 1.1, axis.textsize.y = 1.1,axis.angle.x = 45 )#this should slant the text to avoid the overlap

sjp.frq(base$x, type = c("bar"), sort.frq = c("desc"), geom.colors = "grey")
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you want to wrap long labels into more lines, you can use the `wrap.labels`-argument:

```
sjp.frq(base$x, wrap.labels = 10)
```

Or you change the angle of the axis labels. `sjp.frq()` returns a `data` and a `plot` object, so you can add ggplot-layers easily, or add function like `label_angle()`:

```
sjp.frq(efc$e42dep)$plot + label_angle(90)
```